# LDAP Search Multiple Servers and Domains (PHP)

Tags: php, ldap

So I am trying to search AD by username with PHP and LDAP. However, there are multiple servers, and multiple domains. I figured out how to make the login work smoothly, well as far as I tested at least. However, the search function is a little bit harder.

```
        $Servers = $LDAP['LDAPSrvs'];
        $Domains = $LDAP['LDAPDoms'];

        $sLoop = 0;
        $dLoop = 0;

        foreach($Servers as $Server)
        {
            $sLoop++;

            $connect = 'ldap://'.$Server;
            $lcon = ldap_connect($connect);

            ldap_set_option($lcon, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
            ldap_set_option($lcon, LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT, 1);

            $bind = ldap_bind($lcon, $LDAP['LDAPUser'], $LDAP['LDAPPass']);

            if($bind)
            {
                $search = ldap_search($lcon, $DN, "(sAMAccountName=$username)");

                if($search)
                {
                    $info = ldap_get_entries($lcon, $search);
                    echo var_export($info);
                    if(count($info) >= 1)
                        break;
                } else {
                    new MessageHandler('No users were found.', 'INFO');
                }
            }
            else
            {
                new MessageHandler('Something went wrong.', 'ERR');
            }
        }
        @ldap_close($lcon);
```

The code above is what I use to search. However, it gives a great delay, and even an error in the server / DN it did not find any user with that username.

I have very limited experience with LDAP and PHP, so I would not really know how to solve this by my self. I always solve things by trying and failing, so eventually I might find a hack that works. However, if anyone can help me by explaining to me how it could be done, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ldap_count_entries()` to get a fast count back from the server to see whether something was found at all. That might be faster than first retrieving the search result and seeing that nothing is in there.

So it might look something like this:

```
foreach($Servers as $Server) {
    $sLoop++;

    $connect = 'ldap://'.$Server;
    $lcon = ldap_connect($connect);

    ldap_set_option($lcon, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    ldap_set_option($lcon, LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT, 1);
    ldap_set_option($lcon, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

    $bind = ldap_bind($lcon, $LDAP['LDAPUser'], $LDAP['LDAPPass']);

    if(! $bind) {
        new MessageHandler('Something went wrong.', 'ERR');
        continue;
    }

    $search = ldap_search($lcon, $DN, "(sAMAccountName=$username)");

    if (ldap_count_entries($lcon, $search) < 1) {
        new MessageHandler('No Users found.', 'ERR');
        continue;
    }

    $info = ldap_get_entries($lcon, $search);
    echo var_export($info);

    @ldap_close($lcon);
}
```

I'm not sure though that it speeds up much.

You might also add something like an `echo microtime();` somewhere in the loop to see whether certain servers are slower to respond than others.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your answer! I'll test it out, and get back here with the results.

Comment: I edited your answer, set the LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS to 0. That made it search instantly.

Comment: That would have been the next question whether the LDAP-servers refer to external servers. In that case setting LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS to not follow them will speed the search up - for the sake of not searching the complete directory. It depends on your setup whether that's ok or not.

Comment: Yeah, it's a rather large organizations with multiple servers. But that setting works just fine with the setup of the systems it seems.